# Is there a way to work around RatpackPac4j#requireAuth not setting the WWW-Authenticate header?

Tags: java, groovy, ratpack, www-authenticate

When testing Pac4j (2.x) authentication in the context of a Ratpack (1.5.x) app, I find that when I use this handler:

```
all RatpackPac4j.requireAuth(HeaderClient)
```

...Unauthorised requests get rejected correctly with a 401 status, and [RFC-7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.1) states that a `WWW-Authenticate` header should be added, and it is not.

I raised an issue on the RatpackPac4j tracker [here](https://github.com/pac4j/ratpack-pac4j/issues/3), but it was closed as (I infer) "won't fix" since Pac4j v3 implements this properly. And RatpackPac4j has not been upgraded to work with Pac4j v3 yet.

So: is it possible to insert something which post-process all responses to, for example, conditionally add a header based on the response?

Aside - I'm using the following versions in my gradle config:

```
    compile group: 'io.ratpack', name: 'ratpack-groovy', version: '1.5.4'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.25'
//    compile ratpack.dependency('pac4j') // Don't use this, because we need the org.pac4j version
    compile group: 'org.pac4j', name: 'ratpack-pac4j', version: '2.0.0'
    compile group: 'org.pac4j', name: 'pac4j-core', version: '2.2.1'
    compile group: 'org.pac4j', name: 'pac4j-jwt', version: '2.2.1'
    compile group: 'org.pac4j', name: 'pac4j-http', version: '2.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to John Engelman in the Ratpack Slack channel, here is a work-around: use `Response#beforeSend`

```
handlers {
  all {
    response.beforeSend { response ->
      if (response.status.code == 401) {
        response.headers.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'bearer realm="authenticated api"')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this handler must be inserted before any others which may generate a 401 response or the callback will not be bound when they are triggered.